# White residue from ginger juice

Tags: biochemistry

I’ve been juicing some ginger by grating it and pressing it (by hand). A white residue collects at the bottom of the liquid. What is this?

[image: juice in pan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this white residue is starch. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger), Ginger is 17.7% carbohydrates by weight, or 14% excluding sugar and dietary fiber.

I let the residue settle and decanted the liquid. The residue behaved remarkably similarly to wet corn starch. From this, I have concluded that it is starch of some form.

Comment: good point. You can also test it if you have an iodene antisceptic, the soy sauce colored antisceptic. if you pour it on starch it turns dark blue.